# Send byte array from javascript to silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight

Can this be done ?

Below are snippets of what is not working, failing with exception:

[image]

```
function SendBytesJS() {
    var control1 = document.getElementById('sl1');
    bytes = new Array(1, 2, 3);
    control1.Content.MainPage.SendBytesSL(bytes);
}
```

and

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("MainPage", this);
    }          

    [System.Windows.Browser.ScriptableMember]
    public void SendBytesSL(byte[] bytes)
    {
        // never gets here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML bridge does not support byte arrays and Javascript only understands integer and float (actually double).

An array is passed as `object[]` and numbers are always passed as `double`.  Hence your code needs to look more like the following:-

```
 // Warning untested code
 [ScriptableMember]
 public void SendBytesSL(object[] arrayIn)
 {
     byte[] bytes = arrayIn.Select(o => Convert.ToByte(o)).ToArray();
 }
```

Comment: Ok got it, here is a tested method version ----         [System.Windows.Browser.ScriptableMember]
        public void SendBytesSL(object bytesArray)
        {
            var array = (ScriptObject)bytesArray;
            var len = (int)((double)array.GetProperty("length"));
            var bytes = new byte[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                var e = array.GetProperty(i);
                bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(array.GetProperty(i));
            }
        }